# c# change author in visual studio

Tags: c#

A bit of a funny question. I've made a small C# program today as a test to learn how visual studio works. More specifically playing around with the "publishing" portion of the program.

I went to run it on another machine, and it says the author as the program name. Is there any way for me to change this so the author is my name?

Edit:

I've tried this link here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8bw4k20(v=vs.80).aspx

However can't seem to find the setup project folder.

Comment: You mean, like, you want to commit plagiarism? We're not going to help you with that.

Comment: No, I mean Im building my own program as I'm learning C#. The program is completely created by myself. All it does is hello world

Comment: actually thats a lie. I changed it up lately so you now have office icons that you click and it opens up there corresponding program. Just uploading a screenshot now.

Comment: `"can't seem to find the setup project folder"` - Do you *have* a setup project?  It would be separate from your code project, in the same solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understood, you want to change your program's author name. You can change that in AssemblyInfo.cs file under **Properties** in Visual Studio Solution explorer window

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the solution.

In Visual Studio, open up Solution Explorer. Open up the properties menu and open the file AssemblyInfo.cs

From there you can modify details of the program.